# Redundant indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I noticed a strange combination of indexes in one of the databases I was working on.

Here is the table design:

```
CREATE TABLE tblABC 
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    AnotherId INT NOT NULL, --not unique column
    Othercolumn1 INT,
    OtherColumn2 VARCHAR(10),
    OtherColumn3 DATETIME,
    OtherColumn4 DECIMAL(14, 4),
    OtherColumn5 INT,

    CONSTRAINT idxPKNCU 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (id)
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx1  
    ON tblABC(AnotherId ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx2 
    ON tblABC(AnotherId ASC) INCLUDE(OtherColumn4)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx3 
    ON tblABC (AnotherId) INCLUDE (OtherColumn2, OtherColumn4)
```

Please note that column id is identity and defined as primary key.

A clustered index is defined on column - AnotherId, this column is not unique.
There are two additional nonclustered indexes defined on AnotherId, with additional include columns

My opinion is that either of the nonclustered indexes on AnotherId are redundant (idx2 and idx3) because the main copy of the table (culstred index) has the same data.

When I checked the index usage, I was expecting to see no usage on idx2 and idx3, but idx3 had highest index seeks.

I have given a screenshots of the index design and usage

My question is - aren't these nonclustered indexes - idx2 and idx3 redundant? Optimizer can get the same data from the clustered index - idx1. May be it would have got it, if there was no NC index defined.

Am I missing something?

Regards,

Nayak

[image: Index Design]

[image: Index Usage]

Comment: It seems a bit odd to have two NCI on the same column which is the PK/CI - that part doesn't really make a lot of sense to me. Then: since the only difference between `idx2` and `idx4` is the inclusion (or not inclusion) of another column, I'd say yes - the index which includes only one other column is redundant and could be easily handled by the second NCI (which includes both extra columns)

Comment: Since idx2 and idx3 are smaller than idx1 (idx1 *is* the complete table, idx2 and idx3 contain only a subset of the fields), querying idx2 and idx3 might require less page loads if only those specific fields included in the indexes are required.

Comment: @marc_s, PK is on the identity column. Clustered index is on AnotherId, which is not unique(used for joining with another table).

idx1, 2 and 3 are on the same column 0 AnotherId.

Comment: The smallest covering index is the most effective in terms of I/O. The optimizer doesn't care about redundancy. Any query that needs only `AnotherID`, `OtherColumn2` and `OtherColumn4` will prefer idx3 to idx1, and even queries that do need more columns will prefer idx3 if their seeks are fully covered by it (even if an additional CI lookup is also needed).

Comment: As an aside, such "redundant" indexes are typically a sign of someone running the tuning advisor and having it blindly create all indexes, or getting a "missing index" hint in a query and blindly creating *that* index. These mechanisms don't consider the costs of indexes, only their benefits for particular queries.

Comment: Yeah, Makes sense. Thanks. Heinzi, Jeroen and marc_s.

The size of the indexes are 64Mb, 12 Mb, and 17 Mb respectively.

Given the usage, I would think idx2 will be redundant in terms of design.

(I was planning to get rid of one/two of these indexes earlier, but probably, won't worry about it as these are smaller)

Comment: Has anyone considered an approach where we go to the index usage DMV and find the clustered indexes with high seeks - in millions as an example, and add such narrow indexes (of course, after verifying the usage in the queries)?

Comment: I would not typically consider creating these indexes based on what a DMV said. (For most tables, you *would* expect heavy use of the clustered index.) Even though idx3 is smaller than the clustered index, and covering, and so it *does* improve query times, I would want to see some figures about *how much* it improves query times. It's probably far less than linear in the size of the index. This arrangement is also unusual because it implies that the other columns are rarely if ever accessed by queries, which suggests they're possibly no longer interesting to have in the table at all.

Comment: In this specific case, clustered index was used (because we see some usage numbers for CI too). Of course, we do need to check other parameters. 

But what I am asking is has anyone considered this approach? 

Say, a CI is hit 40 million times in a month and it's 10 Gb index. There may be case of queries referring to a narrow NC index, of say 500 Mb, 35 million times.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit odd to have two very similar non-clustered indexes, though they may both be getting used equally. I do also find it positively weird that the clustered index was made on a non-unique field.

Check out the following link for information and a free tool to ascertain index usage. I use this all the time to see which indexes are being used etc.

https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/

For the non-clustered indexes - You can consolidate, and remove the unused indexes as if you're only writing to them, it is a royal waste of resources.
For the clustered index, you ***may*** consider redoing it based on your findings with the blitz index tool.

Comment: A non-unique clustered index isn't as weird as it sounds. Consider a table with historical data, indexed by a (not guaranteed to be unique) timestamp. If almost all queries involve ranging over this timestamp, it's the perfect candidate for the clustered index, rather than a surrogate ID which is never used (or a unique combination of the timestamp and the ID, which takes up more room than the timestamp and the uniquifier). The clustered index shouldn't be *very non-unique*, but some duplicates are OK if it still meets the other criteria. (And yes, I'm talking about a real table.)